# express.js html not loading css file

Tags: javascript, html, css, express, web-applications

i am new to express.js i made a project with express.js in which css file is in public folder and html files are in views folder but when started the webserver the html file rendered but it is not loading any css files i cant see any images too i think it is problem with express.js i tried running the html file with its path it worked when i run the html file with its path

main.js

```
    //Imports
    const express = require('express')
    const app = express()
    const port = 3000
    const path = require('path')
    
    
    //static files
    
    
    // Require static assets from public folder
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
    
    // Set 'views' directory for any views 
    // being rendered res.render()
    app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
    
    // Set view engine as EJS
    app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
    app.set('view engine', 'html');
    
    
    //routing
    
    app.get('', (req, res) => {
        res.render('index')
    })
    
    
    
    
    //server
    
    app.listen(process.env.port || 3000);
    console.log('Server started on 3000')


index.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet"
          href=
"https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
   

      <link rel="icon" href="../public/img/kisspng-portable-network-graphics-computer-icons-transpare-braingoodgames-5c9d9c5093e378.8617067815538330406058.png" type="image/x-icon">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

      <script type="text/javascript">
         
         </script>




     
      <script async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js?client=ca-pub-1592285788506158"
     crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

      <div class="topnav">
         <div class="hover-underline-animation">
        
       <a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a> 
         <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
         <a href="aboutus.html">About Us</a>
         <a href="https://stats.uptimerobot.com/V2x6XC2PP5">Status</a>
         
         </div>

      </div>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../public/css/style.css">
      <title>Beast Bot</title>
   </head>  
   <body>

      <div class="container">

      


        <div class="title">
           <p class="infotit">Hover the title</p>
           <P  class="anime"><span>Beast Bot :)</span></P>
         <div class="hideme">
              <img class="img" src="../public/img/kisspng-portable-network-graphics-computer-icons-transpare-braingoodgames-5c9d9c5093e378.8617067815538330406058.png">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="hide me">
        <h1 class="trust">Trusted by 10,000+ people</h1>
      </div>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <div class="hideme">
        <div  class="info">
           <div class="hideme">
           <p class="quote">A perfect moderation and fun bot<br>for your Discord Server</p>
         </div>
           <BR>
            <br>
            <a  href="https://discord.com/api/oauth2/authorize?client_id=876824416531664896&permissions=536870907895&scope=bot" class="btn" >Invite
            </a>
            <p class="quoto">Beast Bot is trusted by more than 10,000 people</p>
           <div class="h11">
            <h1>Features</h1>
            <br>
            <h3 class="h33">Moderation</h3>
            <img src="../public/img/features.png" class="features_img">
            <p class="f_txt">A perfect moderation bot for your discord server with commands like ban,kick,mute,lock</p>
            <br>
            <br>
            <h3 class="muchmore_txt">Much More</h3>
            <img src="../public/img/muchmore.png" class="muchmore">
            <P class="more_txt">Many more fun and anime commands like animegif,meme,cute and many more</P>
         </div>
         </div>
      </div>

        
    </div>
    

    <script src="../public/js/script.js"></script>
   </body>
   <div class="footer"> 
      <br>
      <br>
   <footer><P><i class="fa fa-github"  ></i> <i class="fa fa-copyright"></i> CaptainBeast#1394 - 2021</P></footer>
   <a href="https://discord.gg/wYSDCaRSZw">Join our official server</a>
</div>
</html
```

> 

style.css

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Archivo:400,700');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oswald&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Code+Pro');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300&display=swap');   
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:wght@300&display=swap');
/*Desktop*/

.container{
    height: 200vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #90d5ec;
  background-image: linear-gradient(315deg, #90d5ec 0%, #fc575e 74%);

    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    padding-left: 5%;
    padding-right: 5%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
    
}
.title{
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-size: 72px;
    color: black;
    position: relative;
    top: 200px;
    margin-left: 200px;
    user-select: none;
}
/* Add a black background color to the top navigation */
.topnav {
    background-color: black;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  
  /* Style the links inside the navigation bar */
  .topnav a {
    float: left;
    color: #0087ca;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "Nunito", sans-serif;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
  }
  
  /* Change the color of links on hover */
  .topnav a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
    color: black;
  }
  
  /* Add a color to the active/current link */
  .topnav a.active {
   
    color: #0087ca;
  }
  .title .img{
      width: 400px;
      height: 400px;
      left: 600px;
      bottom: 250px;
      position: relative;
  }
  .infotit{
    font-size: 10px;
  }
  .hover-underline-animation a{
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    color: #0087ca;
  }
  
  .hover-underline-animation a:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    transform: scaleX(0);
    height: 6px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #0087ca;
    transform-origin: bottom right;
    transition: transform 0.25s ease-out;
  }
  
  .hover-underline-animation a:hover:after {
    transform: scaleX(1);
    transform-origin: bottom left;
  }


  /*Stuff not to be shown in desktop*/
  @media only screen and (min-width: 900px){

    .trust{
      font-size: 26px;
      font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
      position: relative;
      
      text-align: center;
    }
    .info .quote{
      font-size: 36px;
      font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
      position: relative;
      text-align: center;
      bottom: 100px;
    }
    .info .btn{
      display: inline-block;
      background: linear-gradient(45deg, #87adfe, #ff77cd);
      border-radius: 6px;
      padding: 10px 20px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #fff;
      box-shadow: 3px 8px 22px rgba(94,28,68.0.15);
      position: relative;
      margin-left: 650px;
      bottom: 100px;
      
    
    
    }
    .info .quoto{
      text-align: center;
      font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
      font-size: 36px;
      bottom: 50px;
      position: relative;
    }
    .info .h11{
      text-align: center;
      position: relative;
      bottom: 20px;
      font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
      font-size: 20px;
  
    }
    .info .h11 .h33{
      color: red;
    }
    .info .h11 .muchmore_txt{
      color: red;
    }
    .f_txt{
      font-size: 26px;
    }
    .more_txt{
      font-size: 26px;
    }
    .footer{
      font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
      text-align: center;
      background-color: gray;
      height: 100px;
    }
    
       

  }
  .anime {
    font-size: 5vw;
    cursor: cell;
    
    line-height: 5.5vw;
  }
  
  .anime {
    transition: color 3s;
    transition-delay: 1s;
    letter-spacing: -0.2vw;
  }
  
  .anime span:hover {
    transition: color 0s;
  }
  
  .anime span:nth-child(1n):hover {
    color: #9875E0;
  }
  
  .anime span:nth-child(2n):hover {
    color: #53FBDD;
  }
  
  .anime span:nth-child(3n):hover {
    color: #00A4DD;
  }
  .hideme
{
    opacity:0;
}





/*Mobile*/
@media screen and (max-width: 640px){
.title .img{
    display: none;
}
.title{
    font-size: 42px;
    position: relative;
    right: 95px;
    top: 100px;
    text-align: center;
}
.trust{
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  position: relative;
  top: 180px;
  text-align: center;
}
.info .quote{
  font-size: 26px;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
.info .btn{
  display: inline-block;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #87adfe, #ff77cd);
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 3px 8px 22px rgba(94,28,68.0.15);
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 120px;
  


}
.info .quoto{
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-size: 26px;
}
.info .h11{
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.info .h11 .h33{
  color: red;
}
.info .h11 .muchmore_txt{
  color: red;
}
.footer{
  font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: gray;
  height: 100px;
}
.anime {
  font-size: 8vw;
  cursor: cell;
  
  line-height: 5.5vw;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change it to

```
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
```

express.static is configured to serve static content from public folder
So the correct path to server static file is to start with '/'